# Is the set of valid sentences semirecursive or not?

Tags: logic, computability

I'm reading the fifth edition of Computability and Logic and stumbling across a seeming contradiction. There is a paragraph on page 223 which states that according to Corollaries 15.4 and 15.5 the sets of valid sentences and theorems of any axiomatizable theory are semirecursive. Later on in the same paragraph there is a statement that according to theorems 17.5 and 17.6 these sets are not recursive. How to understand these two statements at the same time?

More specifically, how should one understand these two theorems together:
Theorem 15.5 (Gödel completeness theorem, abstract form): the sets of valid sentences are semirecursive.
Theorem 17.6 (Church's theorem): the set of valid sentences is not decidable.

And these two together:
Corollary 15.4: the sets of sentences deducible from given recursive set of sentences is semirecursive.
Theorem 17.4: the set of Gödel numbers of sentences of arithmetic that are true in the standard interpretation is not recursive.

To me it seems that the former ones of both pairs of theorems tell that the certain set is semirecursive and the latter ones that the same set cannot be semirecursive. I'm probably missing something very crucial here, so I would appreciate if anybody could explain where this misunderstanding could come from.

Comment: Where you wrote "and the latter ones that the same set cannot be semirecursive" is "semirecursive" a typo for "recursive"?

Comment: @Nigul semirecursive $\not =$ recursive

Comment: Presumably you are looking at Boolos, Burgess and Jeffrey, which I don't have to hand. In addition to Bram28's comment, note that the set of valid sentences of any axiomatizable theory means the set of sentences that hold in every model of the theory. This doesn't conflict with the statement about sentences of arithmetic that are true in the standard interpretation, because the theory comprising those sentences is not recursively axiomatizable.

Comment: The set of *valid* sentences is semi-r; the set of "non-valid" (i.e. its compement) in **not** semi-r. A well known result of computability th says that: a set $A$ is *recursive* iff $A$ and its complement are both semi-r. Thus, if the set of "non-valid" is not semi-r, it follows that the set of valid is **not** recursive.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes the given book is by Boolos, Burgess and Jeffrey. I do understand the difference between recursiveness and semirecursivess of the sets, this I think is well explained in the book. Maybe I need to clarify what I'm struggling with. [to be continued]

Comment: In the same book theorem 17.3 (Tarski's theorem) states that the set of Gödel numbers of sentences of language of arithmetic that are true in the standard interpretation, is not arithmetically definible. This is a consequence of lemma 17.2 which sais that if T is a consistent theory extending Q (arithmetic), then the set of Gödel numbers of theorems of T is not definable in T. In the proof of the latter I think only arithmetical semidefinability was used and this causes lot of confusion to me.

Comment: I probably would understand all these theorems if the former ones (15.4, 15.5) say that the given sets are semirecursive and the latter ones (17.4, 17.6) just narrow it down saying that they are not recursive. To me it seems, however, that what they actually say is that the given sets are neither recursive nor semirecursive.

Comment: The hints for this come out also later in the book where the failure of (abstract) Gödel completeness theorem for 2nd order logic is proved. The statement there is that the sentences of the language of arithmetic true in the standard interpretation is nor atithmetical by Theorem 17.3 and a fortiori not semirecursive. What am I missing here? Sorry about multiple comments, I don't know how to post one long comment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're confused over the distinction between *provability from a given theory* and *truth in a given model*.

- A sentence is valid if it is true in every model. By the Completeness Theorem, this is the same as being provable from the empty theory $\emptyset$. The set of valid sentences is indeed semirecursive; more generally, ...
- ... for any recursive set of sentences $T$, the set $Ded(T)$ of things provable from $T$ is semirecursive. That said, $Ded(T)$ is **not always** recursive, even if $T$ is; there are some recursive $T$ for which $Ded(T)$ is recursive (e.g. [the theory of real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers)), and some for which it isn't (e.g. [(first-order) Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic)). But meanwhile ...
- ... the sentences true in the standard model of arithmetic - often denoted "$Th(\mathbb{N})$" - is quite a different animal altogether. Remember that being provable from $T$ means being true in **every model of $T$**; here, instead, we're fixing a *specific* model and asking what is true *in it*.

So there is no contradiction between the statements $$\mbox{The set of consequences of a recursive theory is semirecursive}$$ and $$\mbox{$Th(\mathbb{N})$ is not arithmetically definable (in particular, not semirecursive)}$$ since $Th(\mathbb{N})$ is not, in fact, the set of consequences of any recursive theory.

Note that the previous sentence **is in fact what the incompleteness theorem says** (or one of its versions, anyways) - that any recursive set of sentences true of the standard model is not complete. (And Tarski improves this greatly.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this fully answers my question!